# AJAX - Change innerHTML of element on change event in selection input not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, onchange

I am trying to get the value of a product from a database when the user makes the selection in a `<select>` element and display said value obtained through AJAX in a element but its not working, if i go to the `precio.php?q=PRODUCTO%201` it does give me the desired result `10` which makes me think the code inside the php file is correct, the issue must reside in the `<script>` section or the `<select>` element.

This is my AJAX function in the `<head>`

```
<script>
    function precioProd(str) {
        if (str=="") {
            document.getElementById("precio").innerHTML="";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("precio").innerHTML = this.responseText;
          }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "precio.php?q="+str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
      }
    }
</script>
```

This is my `<select>` element in the `<body>`

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Elige un Producto</label><br>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <select class="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2" id="producto" name="producto" onchange="precioProd(this.value)" required>
            <option selected>Elegir...</option>
    <?php require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/fetch_lista_productos_compra.php'; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<h3 id="precio" name="precio"></h3>
```

This is the content of `precio.php`

```
<?php 
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/db_key.php';

$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$q = $_GET["q"];

$sql = "SELECT precio FROM productos WHERE titulo = '".$q."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['precio'];
}
?>
```

As always any kind of help would be greatly appreciated and thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added an additional `}` at the end of your script. The following is OK.

```
<script>
    function precioProd(str) {
        if (str=="") {
            document.getElementById("precio").innerHTML="";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("precio").innerHTML = this.responseText;
          }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "precio.php?q="+str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
</script>
```